# Python 3 turtle speed of drawing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am creating a game in python using `turtle` but I am unable to control the speed of the turtle in the loop as the speed of the turtle is 0. It is supposed to run like flash but it is running at normal speed

```
import turtle
c=turtle.Screen()
a=turtle.Turtle()
a.speed(0)
b=True
def ch( a , d):
      global b
      b = False
while b:
      a.fd(1)
      c.onclick(ch)
c.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?
What do you want to achieve?
And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am creating a game in python using turtle but i am able to control the speed of the turtle in the loop

Comment: as the speed of the turtle is 0 and it is supposed to be run like flash but it is running like normal speed

Comment: The screen has to repaint, which takes a small amount of time. Try by increasing the forward distance `a.fd(10)`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`speed(0)` can only speed up the animations a bit.
Try using `c.tracer(0, 0)`

This fully disables all animations, and should result it a bit more of a speed up. Although, to refresh the screen you'll need to call `c.update()`

Comment: Can you demonstrate this speed up for the OP's code?  The `tracer(0)` and `update()` combination gain speed by hiding the details of complex drawing but are there any steps to hide when the drawing consists solely of `fd(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is structured incorrectly.  You don't need to call `onclick()` in a loop, it simply sets a handler function so only needs to be called once.  Also, `mainloop()` should be running the events, not called after the events are over.

I don't believe you're going get any more speed out of this code unless you increase the forward distance.  Simply increading to `fd(3)` will make a noticeable differece.  My rework of your code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def click_handler(x, y):
    global flag
    flag = False

def turtle_forward():
    if flag:
        turtle.forward(3)
        screen.ontimer(turtle_forward, 0)

flag = True

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(click_handler)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle_forward()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: no still not able to achieve the full speed of the turtle please help I am stuck for long